# Export large mount of data in a zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, export

I'm exporting some data from my server to the client.

It's an zip archive but when the amount of data is to big : TimeOut !

```
#On my controller
def export
  filename = 'my_archive.zip'
  temp_file = Tempfile.new(filename)
  begin
    Zip::OutputStream.open(temp_file) { |zos| }
    Zip::File.open(temp_file.path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zip|
      @videos.each do |v|
        video_file_name = v.title + '.mp4'
        zip.add(video_file_name, v.source.file.path(:original))
      end
    end
    zip_data = File.read(temp_file.path)
    send_data(zip_data, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => filename)
  ensure
    temp_file.close
    temp_file.unlink
  end
end
```

I'm using `PaperClip` to attach my video on my app.

Is there any way to create and upload the zip (with a stream?) without a too long wait?

Comment: Can you post the exact error? What's your client ? S3 ?

Comment: I think that a good answer to that issue is to use redis with sidekiq or resque to put in a queue the process for building the zip file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [zipline gem](https://github.com/fringd/zipline).  It claims to be "Hacks on Hacks on Hacks" so heads up!  Looks very easy to use though, worth a shot.

Comment: I just found that and test it. On my test servers it's wonderful. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's working but there's problem not directly linked to this gem that I post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093672/long-request-and-streaming).